# Create multiple rasters in PostGIS from a (xyz) table

Tags: raster, postgis, r, postgresql, database

I'm having a hard time understanding how PostGIS works in terms of raster creation. Let's say I have a table with 14 columns: the first two are *x* and *y* coordinates followed by the air temperature for each month.

Is it possible to create a raster stack in PostGIS using the coordinates and values from table `myrast`? What exactly are the steps to do that?

I can supply an example of the data using R:

```
library(terra)
library(RPostgres)
library(DBI)

# Download a file
destfile = paste0(getwd(), '/', 'mytemp.nc')
download.file('https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov/Datasets/gistemp/combined/1200km/air.2x2.1200.mon.1991-2020.ltm.comb.nc', 
              destfile = destfile, mode = "wb") # 1 mb size

# Read the file (rotate it and convert it into a dataframe)
myrast = as.data.frame(rotate(rast('mytemp.nc')), xy=T)

# Take only a small sample from the original data
myrast = myrast[1:1000, 1:14]

# Upload this into a local Postgres database
conn = dbConnect((RPostgres::Postgres()),
  dbname = 'postgres',
  host = 'localhost',
  port = 5432,
  password = 'mypassword',
  user = 'postgres'
)

dbWriteTable(conn, "myrast", myrast, row.names=FALSE)
dbDisconnect(conn)
```

Comment: What is the coordinate system of the x and y columns

Comment: the one from example should be WGS-1984.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Good News: There is an `rpostgis` package on CRAN which has a `pgWriteRast` function that can create a PostGIS raster.

The Bad News: You only have another 9 days in which you can use it.

[image]

It works by converting the raster values into PostGIS' binary format for raster data, and then calling `ST_SetValues` on an empty raster created with the right shape and size with `ST_MakeEmptyRaster` (these are PostGIS SQL functions, not R). There's a lot of fiddly code in this function and I don't understand it all, it has to deal with CRS codes and bit sizes and signed/unsigned quantities.

https://github.com/mablab/rpostgis/blob/master/R/pgWriteRast.R

Converting this to run on the modern spatial R stack (sf, terra) is possible but the authors clearly don't have time. But option 1 for you is to convert your x,y,z matrix to a `raster` package raster and use this (that conversion process should be well documented elsewhere, I'm thinking the PostGIS write is the real problem here). But this will fail if you upgrade R and this package no longer works. I joke slightly about you having only 9 days, the code will always exist and be accessible from the CRAN archive, there's just no guarantee it will work.

Option 2 is to wait until this package is ported to sf and terra, or if you can't wait, fund a developer to do it (not me, busy busy).

Option 3 is to wait until a GDAL Write driver for PostGIS rasters exists. The current driver is read-only: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/postgisraster.html but if it were extended to have Write capabilities then you could write your raster data to a PostGIS raster with the standard `terra` `writeRaster` function by constructing a DSN (a string with host, dbname, password, table etc) for your database. Again if you've got money, you could fund this.

Option 4 is to save a `terra` raster as a GeoTIFF using `writeRaster` and then run the `raster2pgsql` command utility which produces SQL that you can feed to a PostGIS. You could drive this from R by using `system` to run `raster2pgsql`

See here for `raster2pgsql` info: https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html